Automatically parse xml tags into fields in logstash
Let's say I have a XML of this structure:
<root>
  <person>
    <name>John Doe</name>
    <age>30</age>
    <address>
      <city>New York</city>
      <zip>10001</zip>
    </address>
  </person>
</root>

Is it possible to have the tags be automatically parsed into fields such as name, age, address etc.?
Right now I have the following logstash.conf file:
input {
   file {
     path => "/home/support/simplexml.xml"
     start_position => "beginning"
   }
}

filter {
  xml { source => "message" target => "theXML" }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "simple_xml"
  }
}

and see the following in Kibana:
Kibana
When I parse the same file in JSON, I'm able to get the separate fields like name, and age show up as fields in Kibana.
